# Как получить список таблиц схемы? HSQLDB

Tags: sql, hsqldb

подскажите пожалуйста. 
У меня создана схема:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS mappedSuperclass;
```

В схеме созданы таблицы.

Пытаюсь получить список таблиц в данной схеме, таким запросом:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mappedSuperclass';
```

На что получаю пустой список(гиперсоник встроенный).

Comment: а что возвращает: `select distinct TABLE_SCHEMA from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` ?

Comment: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA, MAPPEDSUPERCLASS, PUBLIC, SYSTEM_LOBS]

Comment: select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='MAPPEDSUPERCLASS';

Comment: Всё, большое спасибо